# marquee repeating images and pre-load

Tags: javascript, html

How can I convert the below code for JavaScript and make it so it will loop?

```
<marquee behavior="slide" repeat=yes>
<img id="img" src="a.gif" />
<img id="img" src="b.gif" />
</marquee>
```

Comment: Please consider the big red warning box in the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: `<marquee>` is deprecated. Don't use it. Use Javascript instead. Not to mention, search before asking, there was a question exactly like yours two weeks ago.

Comment: i can use java script as i have no idea what im actually doing ... and the question i posted asking what it is im trying to do was closed :( i have no idea what this effect is called or what terms i should look for.

Comment: What actually you want... please be specific

Comment: http://jsbin.com/curupe/1/edit?html,css,output i want that looped in js

Comment: add `loop=999999999`

Answer (score 1):

There is a property of `<marquee>` tag which is called `loop`

you can use it to solve your problem

**Example**

1). If you want to use **behavior = "slide"**

```
<marquee id="Banner" behavior="slide" direction="left" repeat="yes" loop=100 >
```

2). And you don't need to use loop property if you choose to select **behavior = "scroll"**

```
<marquee id="Banner" behavior="scroll" direction="left" repeat="yes">
```

Comment: when doing this it takes about 15 seconds to repeat. im looking for it to be instant,